# Cognos Application-Tier configuration

Tags: installation, cognos, cognos-10

When I configure the Cognos Application-Tier to point to the other components I understand why I need to point to the Content-Manager and the Gateway but according to the documentation (Configure Environment Properties for Application Tier Components Computers) I also need to set the:

```
"6. Change the localhost portion of the remaining URI properties to the name or IP address of your IBM Cognos BI server."
```

Do you know what it means? What is the IBM Cognos BI server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean a dispatcher.  In a multi-server environment, you may have your content manager and your dispatcher(s) in separate installs.

Here's the official definition:

```
    The IBMCognos 8 applications tier contains one or more IBM Cognos 8 servers.
An IBM Cognos 8 server runs requests, such as reports, analyses, and queries, 
that are forwarded by a gateway. An IBM Cognos 8 server also renders the IBM 
Cognos Connection and studio interfaces.
```

Comment: dispatcher means Application-Tier?

Comment: Short answer is yes.  Added a longer answer to my post.